# How can I create group with the same name as the role name in DRF generics APIView

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a new group each time a user create a role, the problem I keep having errors in my code logic, and I don't really know what to do to make it work, here is what I came with so far :

```
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class CreateRoleView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Roles.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateRolesSerializers
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        role_name=self.kwargs['role_name']
        created = Group.objects.create(name=role_name)
        return self.create(request, created, *args, **kwargs)
```

and here is a screen of my problem :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C0Ll.png)

this is my Serializers :

```
class RolesSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
        model = Roles
        fields = ('__all__')
```

and this is my model :

```
class Roles(models.Model):

    role_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    role_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: You must have passed the `role_name` in your POST body, so you need to access it from `request.data`?

Comment: how i can possibly pass the role_name toy the POST body, isnt `role_name=.kwargs['role_name'] `enough ?

Comment: It's already there. Can you try to print it

Comment: At that point the role is not created yet I assume. So just get the role name from `request.data['role_name']`

Comment: I change the first line to that `role_name=get_object_or_404(Roles, role_name=request.data['role_name'])`, but  it seems to be working, but don't create any new object

Comment: Why is `created` included in `self.create(request, created, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Can you also show your serializer

Comment: I update the post with the role model and serializes, and i just assume I should include it in self.create ...

Comment: well thanks for your help,, your suggestion work for me `role_name=request.data['role_name']` Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @bdbd suggested the solution was :

```
class CreateRoleView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Roles.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateRolesSerializers
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        role_name=request.data['role_name']
        # role_name=self.kwargs['role_name']
        created = Group.objects.create(name=role_name)
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```